# Passing references as function parameters in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I dont undesratand in which situations is more convenient to pass references as functions parameters:

```
- (void)exportXMLToString:(NSMutableString **)aString
```

Can I just pass the string by value and have it back when the method finishes to execute ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It more convenient to pass references when you do not want an extra copy of String, 
Extra copy means more space, If you want to read/append the String< It is better if you do not create a new new one. 
You easily do this by passing String value (create a new one) but that's not very efficient. (you want two glasses space to store 1/2 glass of water :) )

Answer (score 1):

You may find the following thread useful. I think your issue is vastly discussed here:
[Use of pass by reference in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249040/use-of-pass-by-reference-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you are trying to achieve, you could just name your method `- (NSString *)xmlStringValue`.

It is a matter of style, I personally only use references in ObjC when I have to (it is not really in the spirit of the language imho), and almost exclusively for `(NSError **)`.